# Microsoft will shutdown IE starting June 15, will vba code that uses InternetExplorer and HTMLDocument still work after the shutdown date?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have a vba program that uses InternetExplorer and HTMLDocument object.  Since Microsoft has already announced that it will shutdown internet explorer starting June 15, 2022.  I am just worried will the vba program that I did still works?  Since I'm not sure if they will be shutting down IE completely.

```
Option Explicit

 Sub automateIE()

 Dim IE As InternetExplorer
 Dim doc As HTMLDocument
 Dim URL As String

 Set IE = New InternetExplorer

 Let URL = "https://www.simpleexcelvba.com/"

 IE.Visible = True
 IE.navigate URL

 Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

 Set doc = IE.Document
 doc.getElementsByName("s").Item(0).Value = "Connect to SAP"
 doc.getElementsByClassName("search-submit").Item(0).Click

 End Sub
```

Comment: See if this [Internet Explorer 11 desktop app retirement FAQ](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549) helps you. If not, you will find out tomorrow if it still works or not. For me it looks like the Windows Update is going to remove IE completely from Windows 10 computers. An alternative can be to switch to Chrome an Selenium which is supported by VBA too.

Comment: Assume IE won’t be there and plan accordingly.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/solved-whats-going-to-happen-to-microsoft-internet/32e237e9-39f7-43da-ab37-0043f3e92ca4

Comment: So far even after the june 15 deadline, the vba code that uses Internet explorer object is still working.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this was a big concern for our team when this was announced a while back. We had over 50 VBA bots that used IE and migrated them over to Power Automate Desktop. Microsoft's new RPA software that works with most of the main browsers. The other option is to download selenium for vba (a little outdated but still works) or head over to python to use selenium which is a stronger solution anyway.